# Uncompress bz2 file from command line on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, bzip2

Is there any tool in the Windows command line that allows me to do this? Otherwise, is there any light and portable application that will allow me to?

Related question, can I rename `.bz2` extension to `.zip`? Seems to work for WinRar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Windows doesn't have native support for `.bz2`. [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) however is free and pretty light as well as featuring command line running. The command you need for it is:

```
7z x archive.bz2
```

Comment: Sweet. Is there a portable 7z build that you know of? I want to use it just once for uncompressing a file and then delete it.

Comment: Goto the download page on the left and in the second box (stable build, not beta) there are a number of links including a zip version - it's the 6th link down.

Comment: As it is not apparent: 7-zip is both a command line and GUI utility. [Easy 7-zip](http://www.e7z.org/) is very similar, with slightly improved GUI features.

Answer (score 2):

The official `bzip2` command line utility is available for Windows.

**Installation:**

1. [Download](https://github.com/philr/bzip2-windows/releases) and unpack the file `bzip2-1.x.x-win-x64.zip` for a 64 bit Windows, or `bzip2-1.x.x-win-x86.zip` for a 32 bit Windows.
2. Install `msvcr120.dll` according to [the instructions](https://github.com/philr/bzip2-windows/releases):

   > All binaries depend on the Visual Studio 2013 C Runtime Library (msvcr120.dll). This can be installed using the [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784) installer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on tanius's answer:

> 1.[Download](https://github.com/philr/bzip2-windows/releases) and unpack the file bzip2-1.x.x-win-x64.zip for a 64 bit Windows, or bzip2-1.x.x-win-x86.zip for a 32 bit Windows.

2. Install msvcr120.dll for v 1.06 and *vcruntime140.dll* for newer versions according to the [instructions](https://github.com/philr/bzip2-windows/releases)

If you're like me and don't know anything about vcruntime140.dll, I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6PTf1ywq6g0) helpful in helping me find out where it is / how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have [Git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/), this includes `bzip2.exe` (along with lots of other GNU tools from MINGW64).

You can use `bzip2` directly via *Git Bash*, e.g. `bzip2 -d my.bz2` (or `bunzip2 my.bz2`).

Alternatively, you can call the executable from windows `cmd` or `powershell`. You'll find it in your Git installation folder, e.g. `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Git\mingw64\bin\bzip2.exe`.

If you're looking to extract a `.tar.bz2` file, calling `tar -xf my.tar.bz2` from *Git Bash* will decompress the file automatically, because it knows where to find `bzip2`.